# how to select only one item in row, attaching index to bool value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a row of containers which I should select and it should change the color, so I created a function hich should change the coor, but the problem is that it change color of every items not one by one. So the question is: how can I attach index to bool value, without using ListView.builder?

function which changes color:

```
   bool isSelected = true;
int index = 0;
      void changeColor() {
        isSelected = !isSelected;
        notifyListeners();
      }
```

part in code where I would like to use it:

```
/// change color
 color: products.isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.orange,
///pressed the button
child: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/phone.png'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        products.changeColor();
                      },
```

Comment: isSlected should be stored to the specific item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below code for one item should be selected in a row and color should change for selected item. It works!**

```
     Widget getRowWithSelector() {
    return Container(
      height: 95.h,
      width: 1.sw,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                updateSelector(0);
              },
              child: getBottomItem('Dashboard', Assets.imageDashboardActive,
                  Assets.imageImageDashboardInactive, isDashboardSelected),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                updateSelector(1);
              },
              child: getBottomItem('Vehicle', Assets.imageImageVehicleActive,
                  Assets.imageVehicleInactive, isVehicleSelected),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: const SizedBox()),
          // this will handle the fab spacing
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                updateSelector(2);
              },
              child: getBottomItem('History', Assets.imageHistoryActive,
                  Assets.imageHistoryInactive, isHistorySelected),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                updateSelector(3);
              },
              child: getBottomItem('My profile', Assets.imageImageProfileActive,
                  Assets.imageImageProfileInactive, isProfileSelected),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getBottomItem(label, imageSelected, imageUnselected, isSelected) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 9.h),
      height: 90,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          AppImage(
            height: 24.h,
            width: 24.w,
            svg: isSelected ? imageSelected : imageUnselected,
          ),
          2.verticalSpace,
          Text(
            label,
            style: textRegular.copyWith(
                fontSize: 10.sp,
                color: isSelected ? AppColor.primaryColor : AppColor.greyColor),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  updateSelector(int position) {
    setState(() {
      final List<bool> selectors = [false, false, false, false];
      selectors[position] = true;

      isDashboardSelected = selectors[0];
      isVehicleSelected = selectors[1];
      isHistorySelected = selectors[2];
      isProfileSelected = selectors[3];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int selectedContainer = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            _buildContainer(0),
            _buildContainer(1),
            _buildContainer(2),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildContainer(int index) {
    return Container(
      color: selectedContainer == index ? Colors.white : Colors.orange,
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/phone.png'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedContainer = index;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```